Why cannot "3.1415926" be rationalized?

Is it difficult for Mathematica to rationalize it?

The Details section of the documentation at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html explains:
Rationalize[x] yields x unchanged if there is no rational number close enough to x to satisfy the condition |p/q - x| < c/q^2, with c chosen to be 10^-4. Because your example doesn't meet this condition, use Rationalize[3.1415926, 0].

another option could be to use SetAccuracy[3.1415926, Infinity]  https://i.sstatic.net/nSiXpLJP.png

FromContinuedFraction@ContinuedFraction[x] works on any real x, but it won't be as accurate a rational approximation as @Nasser's suggestion.

Use the second argument in Rationalize:
Rationalize[3.1415926, 10^-#] & /@ Range[1, 10]


{22/7, 22/7, 201/64, 333/106, 355/113, 355/113, 66363/21124, \ 84468/26887, 86598/27565, 173551/55243}

